# How to use tes4j on windows?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I am trying to use tes4j on eclipse on windows 64bit machine. But when I try to run project as Java Application after adding tes4j dependency like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Following window pops up

[image]

How do I run the app?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to run the app. All I needed to do is select the name of my class in which I was using `tess4j` in the window that poped up.